# How do I make Discord.JS v13 make a role with Administrator permissions?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've seen a bunch of answers on Stack Overflow showing how to make a role with a colour but it doesn't show how to make it with permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a role with permissions using this:

```js
guild.roles.create({
  name: 'Super Cool Blue People',
  color: 'BLUE',
  reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
  permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR', 'KICK_MEMBERS'],
})
```

I have added two examples above `ADMINISTRATOR` and `KICK_MEMBERS`.

Flag List: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

Please note that you're recommended to use `Permissions.FLAGS.<FLAG-NAME>` instead of hard-coding the permission name.

Answer (score 2):

A guild's `RoleManager#create` takes a parameter of type [`CreateRoleOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CreateRoleOptions), which has a property `permissions` of type [`PermissionResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PermissionResolvable). Therefore, you can create a role with specific permissions by calling:

```js
guild.roles.create({
    permissions: "ADMINISTRATOR"
});
```